# While View page opening with post Id, partialview not returning any item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working MVC 5 on c#,
My problem about run partial view.

codes,

Controller:

```
    MiyosContext db= new MiyosContext();
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.IndexId = id;
        return View();
    }
    public PartialViewResult FirmaList(int id)
    {
        var firmalar = (from b in db.Firmalar
                        where b.Id == id
                        select b).ToList();

        return PartialView(firmalar);
    }
```

View:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutGenel.cshtml";
}
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        var firmaId = document.getElementById("gelenId").value;
        $('#firmaBilgileri').load("../Firma/FirmaList/" + firmaId);        
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.FirmaId" id="gelenId" />
<div id="firmaBilgileri">
</div>
```

Partial View not working with "int id".

If i change controller like this, there is no problem:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.IndexId = 2;
        return View();
    }
```

I erased "int id" and view opening without post. Now it is working. Why using "int id" blocking partial view?

Note: it is not about url post function.

Answer (score 0):

Because is needs the `id` from the resource URL:

```
GET /Firma/Index/2
```

You can leave as the former and type this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:portNumber/Firmar/Index/2
```

It should work with the `id` parameter.

So, all you need to do is add a query string to the `load()` request:

```
$('#firmaBilgileri').load("/Firma/FirmaList?id=" + firmaId);
```

Make sure the request actually hits the MVC controller.

Comment: No I didn't ask it. Thanks your answer but i know about url.I will explain my problem widely: First controller i'm using id and so my url Firma/Index/1 and page is opening but partial view not loading. After try the last controller (with out id) and url Firma/Index and page loading with partial view.. (Both of controllers, Index view is same)Thats my problem i have to use this view with first controller but partial view not loading

Comment: I see, I'll expand on my answer.

Comment: $('#firmaBilgileri').load("/Firma/FirmaList?id=" + firmaId); i tried but nothing change. When index controller request id, partial view not working. Yes hit the controller

Comment: Have you tried without the `?` and `'/Firma/FirmaList/' + firmaId` instead?